# Prove directly that $xy - 1$ cannot be resolved into a product of two linear factors

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

(From Chrystal's *Algebra*, Part I)

I'm not sure how to do this – there's no solution in the text.

As I understand it the question is asking that it's not possible to express $xy-1$ as $(x+a)(y+b)$. But seeing a fully worked solution would be interesting.

Comment: Dear baxx, how come you use that very old text by Chrystal? Is it a book required by your school?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg not required no - I think I read somewhere that It was good so thought I'd have a look. I'm open to any suggestions if you feel there's a more modern algebra book to recommend though.

Comment: Dear baxx, Chrystal is quite good and my question implied absolutely no criticism. On the contrary, I feel that doing many down-to-earth calculations counterbalances the trend in modern algebra textbooks to ever more abstract points of view.That said, you might also want to learn some more modern algebra but I can't give you any advice without knowing something about you. You might ask for book  recommendations on this site, but then  be careful to explain your background, tastes, goals, school attended, ...

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg thanks, no criticism taken :) I understand that it's hard to recommend things in such a context (and quickly develops into 'how long is a piece of string'...). I'm around High School level maths, and felt that I didn't have a decent grounding in algebra which led to me having problems with other aspects of calculus and such. That's a rough context, but I'm not expecting much based on this I just mention it in passing really.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations, baxx. You seem to be full of initiative and your spelling is perfect: these are very good signs! Good luck in your studies and feel free to ask for help on this site if needs be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we could resolve $xy-1$ into $(x+a)(y+b)$. Expanding we would get
$$xy+bx+ay+ab=xy-1$$
Comparing the $x$ and $y$ terms on both sides, we realise that $a$ and $b$ must be 0, implying that $ab=0$. Comparing the constants we get $ab=-1$. We arrive at a contradiction because $0\ne-1$, so $xy-1$ cannot be decomposed into linear factors in general.

(When $x=y$ we *can* decompose $xy-1$ as $(x+1)(y-1)$, because then $bx+ay=y-x=0$.)

Comment: thank you - this makes sense.